# django how do you pass validation errors from views.py to forms.py

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

How do I raise/pass validation errors from views.py to forms.py?

Should I do:

```
e = sub_form.cleaned_data['code']           
try:
    cde = sample_table.objects.get(code=e)
    de.acts = 'yes'
    cde.save()
except:
    raise sub_form.ValidationError("invalid code")
```

Here's my form:

```
class confirmform(ModelForm):

    code = forms.CharField( max_length=15, label = ("Your Activation Code"))

    class Meta:
        model = sample_table
        fields = ('code',)
```

I know there is a clean/proper way of doing this but I have no idea how to do it and this code raises:

```
*object has no attribute 'ValidationError'*
```

Any advice would be welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you do that validation in the form itself?

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this bit of code

```
from django import forms

raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid code")
```

More info here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#raising-validationerror

Comment: i assume this would be in the forms?

Comment: In the forms, in the views, wherever you want. But it'd be recommended to do the validation in the form (see above link)

Comment: i did it in views and it raises an error

object has no attribute 'ValidationError'

i can't do it in forms because the validation will come from the database
(cheking if the code is in the database)